# Can we change property info mode (can we override a Can Write property to true in extension Method)

Tags: .net, datetime, propertyinfo

I have an extension method through which i convert date time to universal / local time zones. I am getting a problem that whenever i pass List of datetime to this extension method it failed to convert and i am getting exception message on this line

```
Type type = record.GetType();
foreach (var property in type.GetProperties())
{
if (property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime) && ((DateTime)property.GetValue(record, null)) != DateTime.MinValue)
{
property.SetValue(record,                                                 
 ((DateTime)property.GetValue(record, null)).ToUniversalTime());
}
}
```

On Property.SetValue line i am unable to set its value because property.CanWrite is false in this case. I am only getting this issue when passing List of datetime and iterating on its items.

Comment: So why not check `CanWrite` yourself before invoking `SetValue`? If you're reflecting over `DateTime` structures themselves, you're probably trying to set the [`Date` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx) which is, indeed, not writable.

Comment: I need to convert those dates to universal / local as per my requirement.

Comment: But the provider of the type has not *provided* a `set` method. The property in question *may not have any storage location associated with it*, so there's nowhere for it to *store* anything that you try to write to it. E.g., again, the [`DateTime.Date`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,92aa9b2917a74e91) property. It only has a getter because it's *computing* a value.